# Android - send touch coordinates to another device

Tags: java, android

I want to draw something in my device, and the paint will drawn on another device.

For that, I wrote a server that take the coordinates of the onTouchEvent and send them to the other device:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    client.sendMessage(touchX+this.getLeft() + " " + touchY+this.getTop() + " " + event.getAction());
    return true;
}
```

But, because the size of the screens is differnt, the paint is not relative.

What can I do about that?

tnx and sorry for my bad English.

Solution:

This is the new code:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

    client.sendMessage((touchX)/width + " " + (touchY)/height + " " + event.getAction());
    return true;
}
```

Dont forget to multiply in the other device.

Comment: Change it to percentage: (Screen width / Screen X) then on the other phone change the percentage back to coordinates. (Percentage * Screen width).

Comment: thank you  Luud van Keulen.

Comment: I will put it as an answer so it can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

To make it relative you will have to divide the coordinates by the screen height/width.

```
float touchX = event.getX();
float touchY = event.getY();

float relX = touchX / screenWidth;
float relY = touchY / screenHeight;
```

Then on the other device you will have to multiply is by screen size

```
float corX = relX * screenWidth;
float corY = relY * screenHeight;
```